# Django Rest Framework - wrong data validating with nested serializer

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework

Models:

```
class Section(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    building = models.ForeignKey(Building, related_name='sections', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Standpipe(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    section = models.ForeignKey(Section, related_name='pipes', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Serializers:

```
class StandpipeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Standpipe
        fields = '__all__'


class SectionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    pipes = StandpipeSerializer(many=True, required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Section
        fields = ('name', 'building', 'pipes')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        pipes_data = validated_data.pop('pipes')
        section = Section.objects.create(**validated_data)
        for pipe_data in pipes_data:
            Standpipe.objects.create(section=section, **pipe_data)
        return section
```

View is just a regular ModelViewSet. I didn`t override any methods.

I send this data in request:

```
{
  'name': 'One',
  'building': 1,
  'pipes': [
      {'name': 'PipeOne'},
      {'name': 'PipeTwo'},
   ]
}
```

But in validated data i get only

```
{'name': 'One', 'building': <Building: Building object (1)>}
```

In serializer initial data we can see:

```
<QueryDict: {'name': ['One'], 'building': ['1'], 'pipes': ["{'name': 'PipeOne'}", "{'name': 'PipeTwo'}"]}>
```

If i try to get key 'pipes' from initial dict i get only second dict

```
"{'name': 'PipeTwo'}"
```

AND only in string format.
If i remove 'required=False' from it, i get an error:

```
{'pipes': [ErrorDetail(string='This field is required.', code='required')]}
```

Cant understand why it goes wrong.
I tried to use solution from the documentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with my test case.
I sent data using drf 'APITestCase'.
Code looked like:

```
 response_section = self.client.post(url_section, data={'name': 'One',
                                                        'building': response_building.data['id'],
                                                        'pipes': [
                                                               {'name': 'PipeOne'},
                                                               {'name': 'PipeTwo'}]
                                                        })
```

So the solution is to add

```
format='json'
```

So now it looks like

```
 response_section = self.client.post(url_section, data={'name': 'One',
                                                        'building': response_building.data['id'],
                                                        'pipes': [
                                                               {'name': 'PipeOne'},
                                                               {'name': 'PipeTwo'}
                                                           ]
                                                           }, format='json')
```

And works fine